# How to determine the eigenvalues of sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix?

Tags: python, python-2.7, linear-algebra, sympy, eigenvalue

The Python SymPy Matrix API has a [method](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/matrices.html) to determine the eigenvalue. I would like to do similar thing with SymPy MutableDenseMatrix. Unfortunately, the [API](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices/dense.html) doesn't allow me to do it.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Maybe look at implementation of Matrix.eigenvals() and see if this can be implemented for MutableDenseMatrix - or can you for the prupose of determining the eigenvalues by transforming the MutableDenseMatrix instance into a Matrix instance ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant, how can I transform MutableDenseMatrix  into Matrix?

Comment: Did you try already something like `b = MutableDenseMatrix(...); a = Matrix(b); b.eigenvals()` - sometimes it is as simple as this, where a copy of the values of a is used to initialize b ...?

Comment: It worked nicely - only had to install sympy first. Please cf. my answer and if you like it, maybe accept it :-) Thanks for the question, and maybe next time simply try this pattern, when simlar classes have a missing method (and intuition does not make clear, why it is missing in the first place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, it must of course be a square matrix, but then simply construct a Matrix out of your MutableDenseMatrix:

```
>>> from sympy.matrices.dense import MutableDenseMatrix
>>> from sympy.matrices import Matrix
>>> a = MutableDenseMatrix([[1,0,0], [0,0,0], [2, -2, 3]])
>>> b = Matrix(a)
>>> b.eigenvals()
{0: 1, 1: 1, 3: 1}
```